# Use of | in java

Tags: java, bitwise-operators, bitwise-or

I came across a java code in which the constant has been defined in the following way

```
 static final char   FM = (char) (ConstantsSystem.DOUBLE_BYTE_SEP | 0xFE);
```

what is the use of `|` in this code?

Comment: Well, `|` is the [bitwise OR](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op3.html) operator...

Answer (score 8):

The `|` is the bitwise OR operator. It works as follows:

```
0 | 0 == 0
0 | 1 == 1
1 | 0 == 1
1 | 1 == 1
```

Internally, an integer is represented as a sequence of bits. So if you have, for example:

```
int x = 1 | 2;
```

This would be equivalent to:

```
int x = 0001 | 0010;
int x = 0011;
int x = 3;
```

Note I am using only 4 bits for clarity, but an `int` in Java is represented by 32 bits.

Specifically addressing your code, if we assume, for example, that the value of `ConstantsSystem.DOUBLE_BYTE_SEP` is 256:

```
static final char FM = (char) (ConstantsSystem.DOUBLE_BYTE_SEP | 0xFE);
static final char FM = (char) (256 | 254);
static final char FM = (char) (0000 0001 0000 0000 | 0000 0000 1111 1110);
static final char FM = (char) (0000 0001 1111 1110);
static final char FM = (char) (510);
static final char FM = 'Ǿ';
```

Also note that the way I wrote the binary numbers is not how you represent binaries in Java. For example:

```
0000 0000 1111 1110
```

would be really:

```
0b0000000011111110
```

Documentation: [Bitwise and Bit Shift Operators](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op3.html)

Comment: And if you inspect the variables `ConstantsSystem.DOUBLE_BYTE_SEP` and `0xFE` you will see that they are all power of two.